# Formidable upload file don't trigger

Tags: node.js, express, image-uploading, formidable

#### Development and test environment:

- Windows 8 64bit
- node version installed 0.10.5
- npm version 1.2.18
- express framework
- formidable module used for file uploading
- Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers

HTML code:

```
<form id="caricaMasterImg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/image/upload"> 
    <input type="file" id="masterImg" name="masterImg" value="Sfoglia" accept="image/*"/>
    <input type="submit" value="carica" id="submitLoadImg" />
</form>
```

app.js code:

```
var image = require('./route/image');
app.post('/image/upload', image.upload);
```

routes/image.js code:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir =  path.join(__dirname, 'tmp');
    console.log('Upload directory is: '+form.uploadDir);
    fs.exists(form.uploadDir, function (exists) {
        console.log('is an existing directory? '+exists);
    });
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log(fields);
        console.log(files);
    }); 
};
```

#### The issue:

When submit button is clicked I expect to see the file logged with console.log(files) instruction. Log writes:

*Upload directory is: C:\Liber-I\app\FileSystemManager\routes\tmp
is an existing directory? true*

No more log is written on application console for several minutes.
I test the case of no-file submission and it seems it is acting the same! It is a **too weired behaviour to be a nodejs problem**, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not familiar with formidable but why not use **connect-multiparty** or **connect-busboy** as they are officially supported by **express**: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect?_ga=1.197483695.1434071463.1390859279#middleware

Comment: What middleware are you using before that `/image/upload` route?

Comment: @mscdex I think I use no other middleware before /image/upload , but I am not sure i am getting your question rightly.

Comment: @Jordonias I took your suggest and tried to use connect-multiparty. I need to test my code a little bit more, but by now the uploaded file is logged as a JSON object on my route function (as expected), is physically uploaded into default upload folder. I would like to set a different upload directory with: 
`var myPath = path.join(__dirname,'/tmp'); var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart({uploadDir : myPath});`
but the default folder is still used.

Comment: What I was getting at is that you have to have some kind of multipart-capable body parsing middleware `use()`d before that route.

Comment: @mscdex here middleware used before app.js code:
- app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
- app.use(express.logger('dev'));
- app.use(express.json());
- app.use(express.urlencoded());
- app.use(express.bodyParser());
- app.use(express.query());
- app.use(express.methodOverride());
- var sessionStore = new connect.middleware.session.MemoryStore();
- app.use(express.cookieParser());
- app.use(express.session({
 secret : secret,
 cookie: {expires: false, maxAge: maxAge},
 store: sessionStore
}));
- app.use(app.router);
- app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did **nothing wrong**. Truth is I am not able to fix this problem, so I decided for a good work around. I choose to use **[connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty)** for file uploading and it is working *just great*.